# Adding a collider that interacts only with raycasts in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I made a trail in my program, which I would like to be clickable, like a button.
I thought about adding a collider, and hitting it with a raycast, but it forces me to exempt it from various OnCollision triggers (it's not meant to affect them at all). How can I handle it efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Unity's concept of physics layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) to solve this problem. You can choose which layers interact with other layers, and pass the layer as a parameter to `Raycast` to restrict to the layers you want to check against.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!